# Webpack - do not insert errors on missing module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

When **webpack** can't process require it inserts error into the code instead.

Creating from this code:

```
var binding = require('./src/build/' + builds[i] + '/DTraceProviderBindings');
```

This code:

```
var binding = !(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'undefined'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }());
```

**How to stop webpack from inserting the `new Error ...`?**

This code is from [dtrace-provider](https://github.com/chrisa/node-dtrace-provider/blob/master/dtrace-provider.js#L18) library. And indeed it's invalid as far as I know, that folder/file doesn't exist. I guess it's a bug in there. The problem is that when we left the code in (the code `webpackMissingModule()`) we start getting unexpected errors inside our application. Removing that line from the final bundle fixes our issues.

Problem is that we are not using `dtrace-provider` library ourselfs. It's a dependency of at least 3 other libs we use. So I guess forking it and changing it ourselves isn't good solution.

Our reduced `webpack.production.js` file:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');    
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
});
```

I tried to use ignore plugin but it doesn't help / maybe I didn't have the correct regex.
I tried to use the replace plugin, it didn't help. Don't know why but I was not able to get rid of that error message. The current work-around solution is to run simple script after build is done which replaces the line aka `"build": "webpack --config webpack.production.js && node fixProduction.js",`

Also accepting any other solution to the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could inject a dummy `require` function into the module using `imports-loader`:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: require.resolve('node-dtrace-provider'),
      loader: 'imports-loader?require=>function() { return {}; }'
    }
  ]
}
```

The final bundle would look like this:

```
function() {
  var require = function() { return {}; };
  ...
  var binding = require('./src/build/' + builds[i] + '/DTraceProviderBindings');
  ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution but I am afraid this would not work if I understand it correctly. The require is used across other files in that package, this would break other require functions used across that package.